# Proof problem with connected graphs, weights and spanning trees

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be connected and weighted graph, and let the weight of edge $e$ be strictly larger than the weight of any other edge. Prove that edge $e$ belongs to some spanning tree with minimal weight in graph $G$ if and only if edge $e$ is a bridge.

I have a hard time with graphs because I always tend to miss some details with the proofs or get stuck on having too many different options to do them. So any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One direction is trivial; here’s a HINT for the other. Suppose that $e$ is not a bridge and that $T$ is a spanning tree of $G$ that includes $e$. Deleting $e$ from $T$ breaks $T$ into two connected components that between them include all of the vertices of $G$. Show how to use those components to get a spanning tree whose weight is less than that of $T$.